# The name 'xx' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, winforms

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. The errors I'm getting are:

The name '_questions' does not exist in the current context - FormChoose.cs

Code:

FormChoose.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class FormChoose : Form
    {
        public FormChoose()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _questions = GetQuestions("1");
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Any input or answers on how to achieve this will be greatly appreciated. Possible reward/incentive for anyone that can help out with ltn's post so I can get it working.

Thank you.

Comment: There is a missing } after button1_click (Form1.cs).

Comment: @AlinaB. I tried adding in the missing } and it threw up a load of build errors.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to access members and methods from a location where they aren't declared.  The method and member you're trying to access (`_questions` and `GetQuestions()`), are part of `Form1`, and you're trying to access them in `FormChoose`.  The only way to do that, is to have a reference to a `Form1` object in `FormChoose`.  And I'm not really seeing anywhere where you are declaring what `path` is supposed to be in `Form1`.

Comment: Forgive me if this is a silly question, but how do I make a reference to an object in another form? I changed the path to "quiz.xml" and the error is gone.

Comment: There are a few ways to do it.  I would suggest you start by reading about [Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x9afc042.aspx).  And follow on that article to anything else that you don't understand.

Comment: Sharing this kind of logic between forms can lead to scalability issues. For starters, I would look into encapsulating all your saving and retrieval of questions in a new controller'esque class that simply defines a get and save for questions. If you create a new static class that has a private List<Question> property and a public List<Question> GetQuestionsByDifficulty() then all your forms can access the controller class and you can either load your data up front or as needed.

Comment: @ltn Could you give me an example of what you mean if you don't mind? I understand how to create a static class but not quite sure in this instance what I should be putting between it - Am I relocating code or typing new code in? Is there a way we could chat / message privately?

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the answer from CL4pTR4P, you have this:

```
private List<Question> GetQuestions(string difficulty)
{
    var quiz = XDocument.Load(path);
```

but path isn't declared anywhere in your code, which is why you are getting The name 'path' does not exist in the current context - Form1.cs

You need to declare it and set it to a suitable value

Comment: I changed it to XDocument.Load("quiz.xml") and the error is gone. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know where quiz.xml resides - you might want the full path Load(@"fullpath\quiz.xml");

Comment: quiz.xml is in a folder with all of the other .cs and .resx files

Answer (score 0):

The attributes _questions and  GetQuestions are declared in Form1 and not in formChoose.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Create a new class to place your question repository.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class QuestionController
    {
        private static List<Question> _questions = new List<Question>();

        public static void LoadData(string path)
        {
            //Load Data from path->_questions
        }

        public static List<Question> GetQuestionsByDifficulty(int difficulty)
        {
            return _questions.Where(p => p.Difficulty == difficulty).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

2 - Load your repository in application startup code. In your case:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    QuestionController.LoadData("");
}
```

You should be able to access the question controller methods whenever it is in scope.

Comment: Thank you, although I'm not sure what code goes in the LoadData part? I feel horrible asking a lot of things but I'm really quite stuck as I've never dealt with this sort of stuff before. Thank you for responding though.

Comment: I have the code in a .zip if it will help you understand my confusion? I'd greatly appreciate if you could help out as it is the last major stumbling block I have in my project.

Comment: If anyone could add to this or help out that'd be great. Possibly a reward will be given if I get it working.

Comment: please email me at km.joinery@gmail.com if you have the time