# The name "xx" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

My program keeps getting the error "The name "ok" does not exist in the current context." What am I doing wrong?

```
namespace Game
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool SelfTest()
        {
            bool ok = GameModel.SelfTest();

            if (ok)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Succeded");
            else 
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Failed");

            return ok;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool ok = SelfTest();
        }
    }
}

namespace Game
{
    class GameModel
    {
        public static bool SelfTest()
        {
            ok = true;

            return ok;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because The name 'ok" does not exist in the **current contex**, In `GameModel.SelfTest`. Next time, double click the error in visual studio and it will take you where the error possibly exists.

Comment: Q: What am I doing wrong? A: Ignoring even the basic documentation. Read about variables declaration in C#

Comment: SO isn't meant to be a compiler... A read of the error message should have pointed you towards the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The name 'xx' does not exist in the current context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256896/the-name-xx-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
public static bool SelfTest()
{
    ok = true;

    return ok;
}
```

to

```
public static bool SelfTest()
{
    bool ok = true;
    return ok;
}
```

or perhaps just

```
public static bool SelfTest()
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have only decleared the boolean `ok` in your `Game.Program.SelfTest()` and in your `Game.Program.Main` but not in your `Game.GameModel.SelfTest()`.
Use the following code instead (or you might want to just use `return true`):

```
namespace Game
 {
   class GameModel
   {

    public static bool SelfTest()
    {
        bool ok = true;


        return ok;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not declared `ok` here:

```
public static bool SelfTest()
{
    ok = true; // should be bool ok = true;


    return ok;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `GameModel` class, you're referencing a variable that is not declared.

To fix this, you can just change this:

```
public static bool SelfTest()
{
    ok = true;
    return ok;
}
```

To this:

```
public static bool SelfTest()
{
    bool ok = true;
    return ok;
}
```